# Try Exception in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, try-catch

I have a code to write in python like below: 
Try to load a file,this file generates from a function in different module. So if the file is deleted, we need to run the function from here and load the file:

```
try:
  with (os.path.join(<path>,<filename>)) as f:
      data = json.loads(f.read())
except IOError:
   Call the function to generate the file
   try:
       # To load the file as above try
    except :
       # needed?
```

Could you please help with the code in this second try/exception block ?

Comment: Please format your code properly by selecting it and pressing Ctrl+K. Only use back-ticks ( ` ) for inline code.

Comment: I have changed it, Please look into this. What I'd like to do , go to previous try block from following exception block

Answer (score 0):

yes, something else (not only `IOError`) might still go wrong.

Also, you need to catch `AttributeError`, and not `IOError`, since that is what `with` statement returns on failing.